# Splashscreen icon not showing

Tags: maui

In my .NET MAUI App, I have an SVG that I wanted to use as my Splashscreen-Icon

```xml
...
<MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\mysplash.svg" Color="#000000" BaseSize="128,128" />
...
```

When I change to the following in the .csproj of my App, I can just see a **black screen** on **iOS** (in iPhone 14 iOS 16.2 Emulator). The background should be black, yes. But, I should also show my SVG.

On Android, I even do not see the splash-screen at all. Is there something, I am missing?

Comment: Have you set the build action of your splashscreen to `MauiSplashScreen`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs [Add a splash screen to a .NET MAUI app project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/images/splashscreen?tabs=ios):

1. You need to add your own svg file for the splashscreen, e.g. **mysplashscreen.svg** to replace the default **splash.svg**

```
<ItemGroup> 
      <!-- Splash Screen -->
     <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\mysplashscreen.svg"  Color="#000000" BaseSize="128,128" />
```

2. The build action of **mysplashscreen.svg** file the must be manually set to `MauiSplashScreen` in the Properties window if it' s not being automatically changed.
3. On iOS, when switching the simulator to the verison: **iOS 16.0**, the SplashScreen can be shown as expected, see below output:

**iOS:**

[image]

**Android:**

[image]

Comment: No worries! You may want to achieve the same SpalshScreen effect both on iOS and iOS. However, as you said, on Android, you are stuck with the image within a circle this is because On Android 12+ (API 31+), the splash screen shows an icon that's centred on screen. For more information about splash screens on Android 12+, see [Splash screens](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen) on developer.android.com. So if you want to achieve the same effect, integrating the image full screen on iOS will be inconsistent for Android effect.

Comment: 1) Can I make the image full screen on iOS, or do I always need fixed dimensions?
2) Is it possible to use a Background Image or Gradients instead of a fixed color in .NET MAUI?
3) Can I achieve full-screen image display on Android, or am I limited to this circular image in the middle of the Splash?
4) My image appears very small on iOS despite using Resize="false"/"true" or even BaseSize="1024,1024" to maintain its original size. It's displaying just as a small rectangle. The SVG has a size of 1024x1024.

Comment: 1) No, you can't make it full screen on iOS, see [Platform-specific configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/images/splashscreen?tabs=ios#platform-specific-configuration). 2). No, you can see someone else has raised a feature request, see https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12639. 3) Fo Android, see  my above comment.

Comment: Do you have any ideas what could be the Problem that my image stays so mall. I can see in your screenshot that it is much bigger than mine which has 1024x1024 and is way smaller than yours

Comment: I've tested it again, it's now the same small size as you said, not sure why it was shown bigger yesterday.

Comment: It's like it totally ignores the BaseSize information. A Splash-Screen with such a small image on my side doesn't really look good to be honest and looks ridiculous - strange :)

Comment: Yes, it would be great if it can be fixed, see [iOS: Splash Screen Logo Scaling Issue in MAUI Apps
#15782](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/15782).

Comment: Thank you very much for this link - disappointing to be faced with another bug then... :(

Comment: @Alexander May - MSFT - I found a link with a different approach by editing the Info.plist file. Maybe also something for you if you want to have a bigger image displaying as Splash-Screen

Answer (score 1):

After research, I came to a [description of another customization for iOS and Android](https://nirav-parmar.medium.com/how-to-change-splash-screen-in-net-maui-31ec756a0ce3) and [hint for the use of Colors](https://blog.ewers-peters.de/lets-customize-the-splash-screen-of-a-maui-app#heading-light-mode)

**iOS**:

Navigate to folder `\Platforms\iOS\` and edit  **Info.plist**.

Add a new key/value-Pair with the folder and name of the splash screen image file without files extension, e.g. **Resources\Splash\my_splash.png**. What I found out in [Changes in Info.plist not recognized anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77253401/changes-in-info-plist-not-recognized-anymore) it only worked with **PNG** files in the end. I tried before and thought it was working with SVG files, but in the end only could get it running with a PNG. Also play with the right resolution that works for you.

**Hint 1**: Build action for your Image still has to be **MauiSplashScreen**. This also adds a <MauiSplashScreen ...> section to your csproj.

**Hint 2**: I tried with filenames having 2 underscrores like "my_splash_screen.png" which did not work anymore then. I don't know if this is not allowed in general or the filename/path was too long in the end, but it did not work for me.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    ...
    <key>UILaunchImageFile</key>
    <string>Resources\Splash\my_splash.png</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**Android**:

I had to do some steps to have the Splash Screen with a custom Background Color on **Android**:

1. Add your Background Color in **colors.xml in file `\Platforms\Android\Resources\values\colors.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    ...
    <!-- Just a red Color -->
    <color name="splashBackground">#FF0000</color>
</resources>
```

2. Add a file **styles.xml** if not existing: `\Platforms\Android\Resources\values\styles.xml`
3. Add your Background Color with the name used in colors.xml above, e.g. **CustomSplashTheme**. Should be derived from ``Maui.SplashTheme"```:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
    <style name="CustomSplashTheme" parent="Maui.SplashTheme">
        <item name="android:windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/splashBackground</item>
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

4. Activate your **CustomSplashTheme** in `\Platforms\Android\MainActivity.cs`

```cs
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;

namespace MyApp;

[Activity(Theme = "@style/CustomSplashTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Density)]
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
{
}
```

With these steps, I now have a full screen Splash Screen on iOS and also the typical SplashScreen with rounded Icon but a custom background color on Android.