# Changes in Info.plist not recognized anymore

Tags: maui

In my .NET MAUI Application, I used `\Platforms\iOS\Info.plist` to set a custom Splash Screen, discussed in [Splashscreen icon not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77222085/splashscreen-icon-not-showing/77248953)

As this is a different issue I have, I wanted to open this as a new thread here.

Yesterday, everything worked fine and I could see my custom Splash Screen on Android and on iOS.

Then, I tried using *.png and *.svg back and forth and also finally did rename my files. This also changed the files and they lost "MausiSplashScreen" in their BuildActions. So, I also did mark the new files again with this BuildAction, which also changed my .csproj file.

Since then, I couldn't get my Image visible again. All I see, is a black Screen and I am also asking myself, where does this come from? Yes, my Image is also black, but with the reals image in different colors etc.

Is there anything, I have to do again to get my Info.plist file running and using my own Image as a splash? What do these Remove-Attributes in my csproj mean? Since I also use `\Platforms\Android\AndroidManifest.xml` for Android, I thought, I should not have any `<MauiSplashScreen .../>` section in my csproj.

Is there anything, I am doing wrong here so that this does not come up visible again and just showing a black screen when I start my App? What I also tried was setting a `Color="#FF0000"` in the section below which showed a Red Screen when starting my App.

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\mysplash.svg" Color="#FF0000"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

But, to have it working with Android and iOS, I thought, I should not have the above section at all in my csproj and just rely on the settings in Info.plist and AndroidManifest.xml as described in [Splashscreen icon not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77222085/splashscreen-icon-not-showing/77248953).

Here are the relevant ItemGroups of my csproj:

**Application Project File:**

```xml
...
<ItemGroup>
    <!-- App Icon -->
    <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" Color="#512BD4" />
    <!--<MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" ForegroundFile="Resources\AppIcon\appiconfg.svg" Color="#512BD4" />-->

    <!-- Splash Screen -->
    <!--<MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\splash.svg" Color="#512BD4" BaseSize="128,128" BaseSize="256,256" />-->
    <!--<MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\my_app_splash.svg" Color="#000000" BaseSize="1024,1024" />-->


    <!-- Images -->
    <MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\*" />
    <MauiImage Update="Resources\Images\dotnet_bot.svg" BaseSize="168,208" />

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <MauiFont Include="Resources\Fonts\*" />

    <!-- Raw Assets (also remove the "Resources\Raw" prefix) -->
    <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <None Remove="Resources\Splash\my_app_splash.svg" />
  <None Remove="Resources\Splash\mysplash.svg" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\mysplash.svg" />
</ItemGroup>
```

**Info.plist file:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
    <array>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <integer>2</integer>
    </array>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>arm64</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>XSAppIconAssets</key>
    <string>Assets.xcassets/appicon.appiconset</string>
    <key>UILaunchImageFile</key>
    <string>mysplash.svg</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**Hint:** I also tried and deleted my obj and bin directories and also deleted my application files on my Mac so that they have to be reloaded again. I also deleted the entire App from my iOS Emulator. But, my Image did not show up again.

Comment: 1. Have you tried to create an empty project to see if it can work again? 2. Consider adding `LaunchScreen.storyboard` to your Platforms/iOS folder, and refer it in the info.plist, see this [Info.plist](https://github.com/davidortinau/ControlGallery/blob/main/src/ControlGallery/Platforms/iOS/Info.plist#L14-L15).

Comment: I could get it running with a **new** Project and finally also with the **original** project. I think one of the main actions was that I added the relative path to my Image-File in **Info.plist**, so that the entry now is **Resources\Splash\mo_splash.png**. You can see a **PNG** file name. Yes, an SVG did not work for me. Additionally, what also did not work for me was to have a filename with several underscores. In the original program, I did not have the relative path in Info.plist just the filename (with and without extension).

Comment: Additionally, I detected a problem when using a filename like "abcd_efgh_ijkl.png". Either the filename was too long in the end or this isn't allowed at all, but so far it did not work. I also read somewhere that the file name should changed everytime it is changed. Maybe, I used one of the filenames for my file which I have used previously at a certain time, I don't know. Question about the **LaunchScreen.storyboard**: How could I integrate an Image there? I do not have a designer at hand nor do I know how I could use XAML code there or so. Currently, I don't know how to place my image there

Comment: Thanks for the update, so to fix it, you need to add the relative file path(I think saying it as absolute path may be more appropriate) as a reference to your image file(png format) in **Info.plist** like **Resources\Splash\mo_splash.png.**. Also, the name format of image file should be neat and not too long with several underscores.

Comment: **LaunchScreen.storyboard** is used to override the default MauiSplash storyboard when adding at the build time. Since you have fixed the issue, if you are interested in the topic, you can refer to this sample app [DynamicLaunchScreen](https://github.com/xamarin/ios-samples/tree/main/ios8/DynamicLaunchScreen/DynamicLaunchScreen).

Comment: I am interested in this and also see potential for my own needs. So, what is not explained there, is there a way to design these storyboards like in xaml or is Xcode as designer needed and then it can just be copy-pasted and used as a replacement for the original splash storyboard?

Comment: I created a Storyboard in Xcode. Then I copied the source code which contained just the filename of my background image. I tried with putting this image also into the ```Platforms\iOS\..``` folder right to the ```LaunchScreen.storyboard```. Added the code you mentioned into the Info.plist. Unfortunately, without success so far. I am using iOS 16.2 - I don't know if this is legacy code with the LaunchScreen.storyboard or if the Storyboard has to have a certain BuildAction. But it seems like it is not recognized in my app. Just a black background - ```<MauiSplashScreen .../>``` was deleted

Comment: 1. I do have viewed other guys successfully added a storyboard to custom the splash screen on iOS, see https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12917#issuecomment-1406723685 and other useful comments. If it still doesn't work, you can adopt the 
first solution that you've figured out. 2. I'll post an answer and conclude what we achieved so far as this will help others who's facing the same problem.

Comment: Just thinking, but do the .storyboard files need a certain **BuildAction**? And conceptually, is using a .storyboard older or newer conceptually. I think for me, the easier way is staying with my current solution. But, regarding designing where my image should be etc. using a .storyboard provides definitely more design flexibility

Comment: I see other users set the storyboard's **BuildAction** property to `InterfaceDefinition`, however, I don' t see that options in the **BuildAction**. And I agree with you that the most convenient way is keeping with your current solution.

Comment: Thanks for the response, have a great day!

Comment: Also corrected slightly before in the related issue’s answer. Hope it is helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the actions that you can take to fix the issue:

1.You need to add the relative file path as a reference to your image file(png format) like `Resources\Splash\mo_splash.png` in **Info.plist**.

2.The name of the image file that you customized for the [SplashScreen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/images/splashscreen?tabs=android) should be brief and not too long with several underscores.

3.This is a supplement for the topic of more advanced splash screen scenarios, see [Custom splash screens for per-platform scenarios #1222](https://github.com/dotnet/docs-maui/issues/1222). Since iOS easily produces storyboard errors, [dotnet/maui#12917](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12917) mentions how to do this correctly on iOS.

Answer (score 1):

**Launchscreen.storyboard**:

This answer provides the steps I did to get the LaunchScreen.storyboard working

1. Design your LaunchScreen.storyboard in **XCode** on the Mac
2. **Important**: Copy the storyboard directly to your Project Folder. As described in a Hint on another place, it also **did not work** for me when I tried to import it to `\Platforms\iOS\LaunchScreen.storyboard`. It also lead to the following compile error: **The file 'Platforms/iOS/LaunchScreen.storyboard' conflicts with 'Platforms/iOS/LaunchScreen.storyboard'.**
3. Copy your SplashScreen Image, which has to be a **PNG** to `Resources\Images\...`, not `\Resources\Splash\...` or so.
4. In csproj set the Image as `<BundleResource .../>`. You can also just do it when target is `net7.0-ios`:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <None Remove="Resources\Images\mo_splash.png" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net7.0-ios'">
  <BundleResource Include="Resources\Images\mo_splash.png" />
</ItemGroup>
```

5. Set **BuildAction** for your **storyboard** as `<InterfaceDefinition .../>` in your csproj directly. It is not available in File Properties.

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <InterfaceDefinition Include="LaunchScreen.storyboard" />
</ItemGroup>
```

6. In my Project File (csproj), I also integrated the normal `<MauiSplashScreen .../>` just when target it not `net7.0-ios`.

```xml
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'!='net7.0-ios'">
  <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\mo_splash.png" Color="#000000" BaseSize="768,768" Resize="false"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

7. **Info.plist** also had to have the filename with extension (**LaunchScreen.storyboard**) in the value for the `UILaunchStoryboardName` key:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    ...
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen.storyboard</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

8. Also important was to delete the **bin** and **obj** folder before trying

**Hint**: The build conditions regarding `net7.0-ios` could be specified even more precisely if needed.

**Relevant sections of Project File (csproj)**:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    ...

    <ItemGroup>
        <!-- App Icon -->
        <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" Color="#512BD4" />

        <!-- Images -->
        <MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\*" />
        <MauiImage Update="Resources\Images\dotnet_bot.svg" BaseSize="168,208" />

        <!-- Custom Fonts -->
        <MauiFont Include="Resources\Fonts\*" />

        <!-- Raw Assets (also remove the "Resources\Raw" prefix) -->
        <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
    </ItemGroup>
    
    
    <!-- SplashScreen conditional when not net7.0-ios -->
    <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'!='net7.0-ios'">
      <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\mo_splash.png" Color="#000000" BaseSize="768,768" Resize="false"/>
    </ItemGroup>

    <!-- BuildAction for LaunchScreen.storyboard set to InterfaceDefinition -->
    <ItemGroup>
        <InterfaceDefinition Include="LaunchScreen.storyboard" />
    </ItemGroup>
    
    <!-- Integrate SplashScreen Image in 'Resources\Images\mo_splash.png' also conditional -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <None Remove="Resources\Images\mo_splash.png" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net7.0-ios'">
      <BundleResource Include="Resources\Images\mo_splash.png" />
    </ItemGroup>
    
    ...

</Project>
```

Comment: Good catch and nice job!