# .NET Maui splash screen on iOS does not resize

Tags: ios, maui, splash-screen

I'm working on a .NET Maui project. I am currently trying to implement a splash screen with a custom logo and background colour. Android displays well after setting the correct value on the BaseSize property within the project file.

The problem is on iOS where the beginning and end of the logo appear off the screen. No matter what I set the BaseSize to the image doesn't update in size, it remains the same.

Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I reproduced your issue, and this issue can be tracked on this thread: [iOS: Splash Screen Logo Scaling Issue in MAUI Apps](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/15782)

Comment: You could also read about my experiences with iOS Spalsh Screens. I finally moved to a **Storyboard** designed in XCode. I can also set the Contraints for Compact/Regular Heights and Widths in XCode to make the designs and where the elemens are located in Portrait and Landscape Orientation and on different Devices or Screen sizes. So far, I am totally happy with this flexibility and the way it looks. I can really recommend it and you can read about the answers regarding the use StoryBoards:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77253401/changes-in-info-plist-not-recognized-anymore

Comment: @OXO I have tried importing the storyboard file from XCode but the storyboard contains an image asset. .NET Maui doesn’t support the assets folder on iOS.

Comment: In XCode my image is placed below the Project folder in a Folder ```MyXCodeProject\Resources\Splash\MyImage.png```. In my Storyboard the Image is just put into an Image View. You can then copy the Code of your **LaunchScreen** from XCode to your **LaunchScreen.storyboard** file in VS. This file should be placed directly below your App-Project-Folder. Your image has to be a **PNG** and put in folder ```\Resource\Images\..```.

Comment: @OXO create an answer and I will mark it as the accepted answer. Well done for figuring out this workaround!

Comment: Just added the answer below - hope it helps. Especially figuring out how to layout for different orientations was really valuable for my own SplashScreen in the end. So, I am able to have good layouts on different devices and orientations right now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could design your own **LaunchScreen-Storyboard** in **XCode** and add the Source-Code to your App-Projects' **LaunchScreen.storyboard** file:

[image]

1. Add your SplashScreen-Image as **PNG** e.g. **YourSplashImage.png** to folder `\Resource\Splash\` in XCode.
2. In your **LaunchScreen** within XCode add an **Image View** and reference your Image there.
3. Design your SplashScreen in XCode. Do it also for **different Views and Orientations (Regular/Compact)**, e.g. for **iPad 10th generation** or **iPhone 14 Pro Max** setting **Constraints** for the corresponding View and Orientation (Portrait/Landscape). This will help to have the layout you want and display your SplashScreen correctly on different devices and also different orientations when you start your app in Portrait or Landscape orientation. You could also have a totally different design for Portrait and Landscape Orientation if you want:

[image]

[image]

[image]

4. Use the Source Code from your **XCode LaunchScreen** and copy it to a File named **LaunchScreen.storyboard** in your Visual Studio App Project. This File has to be located **right in your App Project folder** like this:

[image]

5. Add your Image File for your SplashScreen **YourSplashImage.png** in this example to your `\Resources\Images\..` folder as a **PNG**:

[image]

6. Edit file **Info.plist** in your app folder `\Platforms\iOS\..`

[image]

7. Add your **LaunchScreen.storyboard**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    ...
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen.storyboard</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

8. In your App Project File you have to reference your **LaunchScreen.storyboard** as an **InterfaceDefinition** like here as this is not possible as an Option via Properties within VS, so you have to do it in your project file directly. You can have the **MauiSplashScreen** reference in there to be used as Android SplashScreen File Reference. Also **YourSplashImage.png** has to be added as a **BundleResource** here in source code:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    ...

    <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'!='net7.0-ios'">
      <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\YourSplashImage.png" Color="#000000" BaseSize="1024,1024" Resize="false"/>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <None Remove="Resources\Images\YourSplashImage.png" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net7.0-ios'">
        <InterfaceDefinition Include="LaunchScreen.storyboard" />
        <BundleResource Include="Resources\Images\YourSplashImage.png" />
    </ItemGroup>
    
    ...

</Project>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this . It really helped me out.

Comment: You are welcome, happy to hear it helped