# Black/Blank Splash Screen (Loading Screen) on Apple Device

Tags: ios, .net, maui

I have a .NET 7 MAUI application that is being used solely for iOS/iPadOS. The splash screen is completely black with nothing visible. The SVG file is an image with no black - only blue and white. This happens in deployment to local devices and simulators, as well as when deploying a Release build IPA to the device.

I have:

- A `loading_screen.svg` file in `/Resources/Splash` with a Build Action of `MauiSplashScreen`.
- The file size is 214 KB. The resolution is 1920 x 1080.
- Set the `MauiSplashScreen` tag:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\loading_screen.svg" />
</ItemGroup>
```

- Set the `UILaunchStoryboardName` in `Info.plist` for the iOS platform:

```
<key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
<string>MauiSplash</string>
```

- Set the `UILaunchImageFile` in `Info.plist` for the iOS platform (I have also tried changing the extension in the string below to `.png`):

```
<key>UILaunchImageFile</key>
<string>Resources\Splash\loading_screen.svg</string>
```

Comment: This is a known issue actually https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/18777

Comment: @FreakyAli Thank you, but this also happens on physical devices that I deploy to. That issue relates to simulators.

Comment: I know when you read through you will find this is an issue everywhere and I think its fixed with .NET 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, on iOS, when changing the simulator to the version: **iOS 16.0**, the SplashScreen can be displayed normally.

Also, when adding a new key/value-Pair: `UILaunchImageFile` in Info.plist, it only works with **PNG** format files like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    ...
    <key>UILaunchImageFile</key>
    <string>Resources\Splash\your_splash.png</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Last but not least, you can refer to the two threads listed below, they provide an excellent solutions for the customization of [SplashScreen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/images/splashscreen?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=android) on both iOS and Android.

[Splashscreen icon not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77222085/splashscreen-icon-not-showing/77226419#77226419)

[Changes in Info.plist not recognized anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77253401/changes-in-info-plist-not-recognized-anymore)

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I changed the simulator to iOS 16.0 and still got a black screen. I then removed the loading_screen.svg file, and am using a splash.png image which has a blue background and our companies logo. I put it in Resources/Splash/splash.png, specified that path in csproj: <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\splash.png" BaseSize="128,128" /> (tried with and without BaseSize), and tried with and without the UILaunchStoryboardName and UILaunchImageFile keys. With all of that done, I now get a blank white loading screen.

Comment: After cleaning the solution and restart Visual Studio, I now have a PNG working as a loading screen. I shall try to somehow size this for iPad's and iPhone's. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: @ZachHartt Thanks for the update, glad to see it works!